# how to add outside/external plugin to pgb without npm's cordova cli?

Tags: android, xml, cordova, phonegap-build

Howdy I found on plugreg this plugin http://www.plugreg.com/plugin/uniclau/AlarmPlugin

so how to add to config.xml outside plugin to pgb e.g github's https://github.com/uniclau/AlarmPlugin
without unsupported message

> plugin unsupported: com.uniclau.alarmplugin.alarmplugin

? the main goal install it

I wanted only 2 files: `index.html`, `config.xml` without cordova CLI but if it not possible I'll try use CLI

Comment: @Grisaza, Do you know that  *Phonegap Build* does NOT use CLI?

Comment: I didn't notice but how add to this `<gap:plugin     />`
external (not from pgb) plugin?

Comment: gap:plugin is only PGB. Are you using CLI? This important. Please answer.

Comment: I am not using CLI. So only through CLI it is possible (I know cordova plugin add 'sth') ? To clarify a bit PGB version 1 . That's why I used gap:plugin . So I must use earlier versions with <plugin> supported?

Comment: No. Not clear PGB version 1 is no longer valid. `<gap:plugin>` is deprecated. New is `<plugin>`. See [documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_plugins.md.html#_including_a_plugin_in_your_project). Current default for PGB is cli-5.2.0. You can add plugin from github, but it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On phonegap build you can now install plugins from github
Add this to your config.xml

```
<plugin spec="https://github.com/uniclau/AlarmPlugin.git" source="git" />
```

Comment: Thank you :)
Installed plugin